# Another SQL 'Rows to Columns' Question

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Here is my data:

**ID** 
**Model**  
**Year**  


1    
Civic      
2008


1    
Accord   
2010


2    
Mustang 
2011


3    
Tahoe    
2011

I would like to get this result:

**ID** 
**Model1**  
**Year1**  
**Model2**  
**Year2**  


1    
Civic      
2008     
Accord     
2010     


2    
Mustang 
2011


3    
Tahoe    
2011

Up to 4 cars can be present under each ID and no more.  I have spent a lot of time researching this but have not found a good solution that fits my example exactly.  Perhaps because I don't know how exactly to word my search.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a really great way to do this in SQL.  You might try and struggle with a pivot table, but each entity would need a sequence.

Your best bet would be to arrange it how you want in your output language which will have much better tools available for this sort of thing.

Add a column to each row called sequence (which has 1, 2, 3, and 4)

```
SELECT
id,
Max(case when seq = 1 then model end) as model1,
max(case when seq = 1 then year end) as year1,
Max(case when seq = 2 then model end) as model2,
max(case when seq = 2 then year end) as year2,
Max(case when seq = 3 then model end) as model3,
max(case when seq = 3 then year end) as year3,
Max(case when seq = 4 then model end) as model4,
max(case when seq = 4 then year end) as year4
group by id
```

Comment: I thought about that.  I didn't explore too much but was wondering if there was a way to add a sequence number(count) that reset at each change in ID.  That would obviously allow me to use a pivot.

Comment: I know if you're using sql server 2005/2008 it has a pivot function.  You can also automagically add row numbers using the row_number function.

Comment: row_number is what I needed. I am using SQL Server 2008 which allowed me to use the following to add a sequence number to each record in a table variable I created. `select row_number() OVER(Partition By id order by [year]),id,model,[year] from @tmp` That should allow me to use pivot. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PIVOT tables.  It's ugly, but it works:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#RepeatingGroup') is not null drop table #RepeatingGroup
select 1 as ID, 'Civic' as Model, '2008' as [Year] into #RepeatingGroup union all
select 1, 'Accord', '2010' union all
select 2, 'Mustang', '2011' union all
select 3, 'Tahoe', '2011'

if object_id('tempdb..#tmp') is not null drop table #tmp
select
    ID,
    Model,
    Year,
    row_number() over (partition by x.ID order by x.Model) as Ordinal
into
    #tmp
from
    #RepeatingGroup x

select
    pvtMd.ID,
    pvtMd.[1] as Model1,
    pvtYr.[1] as Year1,
    pvtMd.[2] as Model2,
    pvtYr.[2] as Year2,
    pvtMd.[3] as Model3,
    pvtYr.[3] as Year3,
    pvtMd.[4] as Model4,
    pvtYr.[4] as Year4
from
    (select ID, Model, Ordinal from #tmp t) t
    pivot (
        min(Model) for Ordinal in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
    ) as pvtMd,
    (select ID, Year, Ordinal from #tmp t) t2
    pivot (
        min([Year]) for Ordinal in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
    ) as pvtYr
where
    pvtMd.ID = pvtYr.ID
order by
    1
```

Comment: Unfortunately the car model is an unknown.

Comment: I don't get your meaning?  There's nothing here that's reliant on the data itself.  The only assumption here is that you aren't looking for more than 4 repeating groups (which you said in your question) and that you aren't too concerned with performance.